# Join two tables in one DataSet to populate a DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am currently using VB.NET to try and populate a `DataGridView`.  The issue I am having is with the below.

I have 1 `DataSet`.  In the `DataSet` I have 2 tables:

- `table1`

  - `JobNo`
  - `StockCode`
  - `Qty`
- `table2`

  - `JOB`
  - `StockCode`
  - `DeliveryDate`

I need to join the above and view in a `DataGridView` as shown below:

`JobNumber StockCode Qty DeliveryDate`

The tables are filled with data.  How would i go about doing this? I have already set the relation using the following:

```
dsJoin.Relations.Add(
    JobNumberFlightScreen2.Columns("Job"), 
    dtFlightScreen.Columns("JOBNO"), 
    False)
```

Comment: The usual way to do this is to use a join query to populate a single datatable and then use that as the datasource for the grid

Comment: What @peterG said. Do the work on your database and join the two tables there.

Comment: The reason for having 1 dataset for 2 tables is that the 2 tables are on different servers, i have found a work around for this.